# js-beautify config for Arrays of Objects

Tags: json, js-beautify

Is there any way to configure [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to keep the following format:

```
"structure": [
  {
    "name": "heading",
    "text": "",
    "default": "",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "flickr-album-id",
    "text": "",
    "type": "string"
  },
]
```

js-beautify pulls in the curly bracket of the first object into the first line. I know of the option `keep_array_indentation` but i dont want to disable the general auto indentation because errors wont get fixed otherwise.

The result of js-beautify - that i want to prevent - will be

```
"structure": [{
    "name": "heading",
    "text": "",
    "default": "",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "flickr-album-id",
    "text": "",
    "type": "string"
  },
]
```

Comment: If that's JSON then it's invalid due to trailing commas. If its JavaScript then its ugly due to excessive quoting.

Comment: Yeah that's right, it is a shortened version of the array and so for just a copy n paste error. Keep in mind that trailing commas may be useful in some files where you have large lists that get edited a lot to keep git changes minimal

Comment: My point was that trailing commas are not valid JSON. It seems you're meant to JavaScript instead in which case they are valid, but it's worthwhile to be specific and you tagged `[json]`

Comment: If you don't mind polluting your code with comments, you can add `//` after `[`, and js-beautify won't reformat it.

Comment: You need to set **keep_array_indentation** config option to **true**. You can test it here: https://beautifier.io/